# Logo and Hamburger Menu in Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying to get my logo and hamburger menu for smaller screens to display side-by-side. On my desktop, when I make my window smaller, the hamburger menu is still to the right of the logo:

[image: Hopps Hunter app on Desktop]

But from my phone, it appears like this:

[image: Hopps Hunter app on Phone]

I would like to make the logo about 10% smaller (or more) and have the hamburger menu appear on the right of it from my phone. I don't know what I'm missing here. Here's some of my code:

```
        <nav
            class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between"
        >
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand text-light"
                ><img
                    src="/static/hopps-hunter_logo.png"
                    alt="Hopps Hunter"
                    class="img-responsive"
            /></a>

            <button
                class="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarToggler"
                aria-controls="navbarToggler"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    {% if not g.user %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a
                            class="nav-link pr-3 text-light"
                            href="/user/login"
                            >Login</a
                        >
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light" href="/user/signup"
                            >Sign Up</a
                        >
                    </li>
```

I have tried various things with the bootstrap classes and styles, but can't get it to display properly on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add width="30" or whatever and height="auto" inside the img tag like this:

```
<a href="/" class="navbar-brand text-light">
     <img src="/static/hopps-hunter_logo.png" alt="Hopps Hunter" class="img-responsive" width="30" height="auto" />
    </a>
```

Automatically the hamburger menu will be on the right side responsively.